# Inserted graphic - jagged edges to show that it is just part of the whole

Tags: graphics, pdfpages, include

I would like to make visibly clear, that an inserted graphic is just part of the whole. Since a straight cut just appears as inserted falsy, I was wondering if there are any tricks to show jags for the trimmed sides. Something like this for instance:

[image: jagged page]

Comment: [lpic package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lpic) may help you

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `decorations` in TikZ to morph a path using `random steps`. Of course, you can customize these random steps.

I used a `\clip` with hard-coded coordinates starting from the top left of the image, then top right, down to about 2/3 then left again before closing the path. If you change the `width` of the includegraphics, make sure to change the clipping coordinates accordingly.

Although this can be solved easily using variables.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=15pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, decorations.pathmorphing}

\newcommand\myimgwidth{\linewidth} % one measure to rule them all

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\myheight{(\myimgwidth/4)*2}
\clip[preaction={draw, line width=.8pt}] (0,0) -- (\myimgwidth,0) -- (\myimgwidth,-\myheight pt) decorate[decoration={random steps,segment length=2mm,amplitude=.1cm}] {(\myimgwidth,-\myheight pt) -- (0,-\myheight pt)} -- (0,0);

\node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=north west] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\myimgwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to be a great solution. Would you mind to show quickly how to apply this `TikZ` effect on a includegraphic?

Comment: @Eric This effect was applied on an includegraphics from the start. I only edited it because the randomized line was not horizontal. :D

Comment: I have some tricky effects of resolution --- namely, sometime half of the border line of the graphics appears. Changing `\fill` to `draw[red, fill=white]` I have this: http://i.imgur.com/QIi04xU.png (viewer dependent, but also probably printer dependent...)

Comment: @Rmano That's not a tricky effect, that's the rectangle I have drawn on top of the graphics that is filled with white. I'll find a solution to draw only the decoration.

Comment: @Alenanno yep, I know, the problem is the small vertical gray line which (I think) is a remnant of the underlying image --- there is a problem of resolution in the viewer that makes it show up.

Comment: @Alenanno yes this is awesome! I would like to stretch the pic to `\linewith`. But the "frame" sticks. Is there a way to fix this also? `:)`

Comment: it doesn't expand on `\linewidth`. I am not good at `TikZ`, but maybe it sticks on 8 cm? I added the code to my question

Comment: @Eric Of course you need to change `8` to `\linewidth` in the coordinates. Also, you should remove the code from the question because it wasn't originally there (and it might confuse the readers). :P I'll let you know if I find a better way to do that.

Comment: @Eric See new edit. If using this in an `article` class gives you an overfull \hbox I suggest reducing the width.

Comment: it is nested in a minipage anyway. But this is quite a decent solution! Thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: Idk what you intended this for, but I removed the multiply 2, because this increased the space for my height too much. (`\pgfmathsetmacro\myheight{(\myimgwidth/4)*2}`)

Comment: @Eric The space? Which space? I suppose you could leave `\pgfmathsetmacro\myheight{\myimgwidth/2}` and the result would be similar but better.

Comment: @Alenanno There is a bit whitespace inbetween the end of the picture and the begin of the jags. When I use `\pgfmathsetmacro\myheight{\myimgwidth/2}` this space is massive. Currently I am using /5 which is pretty good. And regarding the overfull box, .999\linewidth in the preamble can fix it already